# What does #[ORM\Column(type: Types::???)] in Doctrine ORM do?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I found in Doctrine documentation this weird definition of **text** column, but my IDE is not liking it.

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;

#[ORM\Column(type: Types::???)]
protected string $content;
```

Instead, `#[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]` goes well.

So what does `#[ORM\Column(type: Types::???)]` actually do?

Comment: The type `Types::???` does not exist in [Doctrine's mapping of types](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/4.0.x/src/Types/Type.php#L23). It could be an example type or a custom type that you have to fill in.Can you post a link to the docs you're looking at?

Comment: Please share more details, like the page that you refer to. If this looks like a bug in the documentation to you, why not report it at Doctrine's issue tracker?